# T4 generated assemblies location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, t4

I'm still fighting with T4 a bit. For better understanding I would like to see the generated assemblies (the ones containing generated `TextTransformation` classes) content (using ILSpy or Reflector like tools). Unfortunately I'm not able to locate these assemblies.

Can someone point me to the standard location the VisualStudio is storing them? How temporal is their existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should turn on debugging for your template

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" #>
```

After that you can find generated transformation class and assembly at

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp
```

Comment: Right, thanks. In general, they are in `%TEMP%` or `%TMP%` and the reason I couldn't find them is they have uniquely randomized name instead of the one I expected (`TextTemplatingFollowedByLongHash`).

Comment: @sharpener yes, names are random. So I always sort files by creation date to see what was just generated

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity of your template, my extension [T4 Awesome](http://www.t4awesome.com) might help.  I have a feature that will automatically show you the generated cs file.  It takes a different approach to using T4 templates by adding a lot of UI tools to visual studio, one of which is a custom editor that includes a preview tab showing the generated cs file.

[image]

If your template is not too complicated, you can just paste your code into the top output part, save and the preview tab will be updated with the generated code file.  I am just reading the same file @Sergey Berezovskiy mentioned in his answer, I just do it automatically inside the extension.

Full Disclaimer, I do charge for the pro version of this tool but this feature is available for free in the community version.